# MVC4 SelectList Issue... setting default selection for dropdown when page is loated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page for managing UserRoles (assigning Users to Roles), and I would like to set the default selection for my role drop down to a specific role, since it is the one that will be added by users most often, but it is not the first role in the list, which is what I started with.

What syntax should I use to select a different item in the Roles list by default instead of Model.Roles.First().ID?  Or is this a waste of time?

Models:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String LanID { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual Division Division { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IncludeInReports { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsOmniscient { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Nullable<DateTime> StartDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual System.Nullable<DateTime> EndDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class UserRoleViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SelectedUserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SelectedRoleID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
    public bool IsOmniscient { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.Nullable<DateTime> StartDateTime { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public System.Nullable<DateTime> EndDateTime { get; set; }

}
```

View: (Create.cshtml)

```
@model HolterManagementUI.Models.UserRoleViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create a User Role</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Users</td>
    <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(h => h.SelectedUserID, new SelectList(Model.Users, "ID", "Description", Model.Users.First().ID))
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Roles</td>
    <td>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(h => h.SelectedRoleID, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "ID", "Description", Model.Roles.First().ID))
    </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Read Only</td>
    <td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(h => h.ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(h => h.IsReadOnly)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Can See Other Areas</td>
    <td>
    @Html.EditorFor(h => h.IsOmniscient)</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Start Date & Time</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(h => h.StartDateTime)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>End Date & Time</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(h => h.EndDateTime)</td>
</tr>
</table>

<div class="buttongroup" align="left" style="margin-top: 50px">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save" />
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("List")'">Cancel</button>
</div>
}
```

Comment: when you are building the model for the view if you set SelectedRoleID to the role that you want selected it should work for you

Comment: @MattBodily: Came here just to say that. I'd make that set in your ViewModel constructor, if possible. I try to put as much as my defaulting in them as possible.

Comment: Thanks. Feeling pretty silly for having missed that.  MONDAY!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a way to know which role should be the default, so either you add a `bool IsDefault` to your `Role` class:

```
public class Role
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
    public virtual String Description { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IncludeInReports { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

And change your view to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(h => h.SelectedRoleID, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "ID", "Description", Model.Roles.First(x => x.IsDefault).ID))
```

**Edit:**

Or you could set the `SelectedRoleID` to the default one (if not set already - for example, if the user is editing it, it could have been previously set) and pass it to your view, and change your view to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(h => h.SelectedRoleID, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "ID", "Description", Model.SelectedRoleID))
```